# EC2 Reserved Intance - What is the difference between Windows and Windows (Amazon VPC)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, reserved-instances

When setting up a reserved instance, what is the difference between Windows and Windows (Amazon VPC)? Will I be able to use AMI's with either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Windows (Amazon VPC)" is a reserved instance specifically for EC2 instances that will reside **inside** a VPC.  If your instance is not inside a VPC, then just purchase a "Windows" reserved instance.

This distinction is to prevent users from purchasing a reserved instance for inside a VPC, then wanting to have it apply to an instance outside a VPC (or vice versa).

Comment: The issue I was having is the VPC acronym itself, I was thinking VPC as in "Virtual PC", not Amazon's "Virtual Private Cloud".